# On Mac Terminal, how can I know where a given script resides

Tags: macos, unix

For example, on my machine, `git` is at `/usr/local/git/bin/git` (I found this by fiddling around). Is there a command I can run on my terminal like `show-path git` which would return the real path? I tried `whereis` but that doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 5):

What you actually need is `which`. Also `type`, which can show you aliases as well.